Error while deleting object in eclipse - object does not exist (SAP BTP, ABAP Environment)
I imported a package with objects (classes,...) from github into eclipse/ABAP Environment.
When I try to open a class, I get a message that the object does not exist. When I try to delete the object, I get the same message. When I try to delete the package I get a message that the package cannot be deleted because it contains objects. Push/pull from/to github doesn't work. I get a message "eclipse doesn't respond" and I have to close eclipse. Unlink the github repository and link it again didn't work also.
Does anyone know, how I can delete the not existing objects and package?
Thanks, Sebastian
I tried to delete an object
